# Is there a saying like "something still bites me"?

Tags: phrases

It's a recurring issue for me that I can't completely remember a saying. In this case I think I've heard someone using something like:

> I've interrogated him and he seems to have an alibi. Something still bites me, though.

So the meaning is like '*still having a suspicion about something/someone*' or '*something is still bothering*'.

Am I making this up or am I confusing it with a very similar phrase? If not I'd be interested to hear more usage examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could be confusing it with *Something still **bugs** me about this, though*. Anyway, in this context the meaning is *Something is still bothering me about this, though*.

Comment: Perfect! I think that's the phrase i was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

As @Radu says, there's the relatively recent metaphoric (informal) usage [[something] still **bugs** me](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22had%20a%20fascination%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22still%20bugs%20me%22&oq=%22still%20bugs%20me%22&gs_l=serp.3...40240.42868.9.43303.12.12.0.0.0.0.88.682.12.12.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.7oWDb1xV2A0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44342787,d.d2k&fp=58e13a8353fb6902&biw=1501&bih=937).

But if OP wants to stick with his metaphoric "bite" sense, the standard idiomatic usage is...

> [[something] still **gnaws** at me](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22had%20a%20fascination%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22still%20gnaws%20at%20me%22&oq=%22still%20gnaws%20at%20me%22&gs_l=serp.3...1600303.1608109.7.1608456.51.33.0.0.0.11.138.2144.31j2.33.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.MVVSeoE01kg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44342787,d.d2k&fp=58e13a8353fb6902&biw=1501&bih=937) *(256 written instances in Google Books)*.

(At least some of those instances will be in relatively "formal" contexts, where **bugs** would never do.)